# How can I create an instance of a EarPluginConvention for my Gradle Plugin?

Tags: gradle, ear, gradle-plugin

I am trying to create an instance of the Ear Plugin Convention , but the documentation is vague. I am currently constructing the object as

```
EarPluginConvention epc = new EarPluginConvention(task.getServices().get(FileResolver.class),task.getProject().getObjects());
```

, but all the properties on this object are null. Is there an other way to get an instance of a FileResolver?

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/plugins/ear/EarPluginConvention.html

Comment: What's the reason to create it?

Comment: I need the appDirName property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new instance of this class it will always be empty anyway, so what's the sense?

I guess you are more after something like

```
project.getConvention().getPlugin(EarPluginConvention.class).getAppDirName()
```

which gets the one that the `ear` plugin created, configured and added to the project and that maybe was reconfigured by the build script